# Google Map Api geocode location works for all location but one town name

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

So, I've got a fully working address locator that can be seen here:

http://www.hwca.com/offices/?location=Wigan&lat=53.5450645&long=-2.6325074

I've tried several town / postcodes and they work fine however if you enter 'Launceston' it suddenly doesn't recognize that specific place.

Checking the network tab on devtools shows that only non-uk addresses are returned on this search but I am certain there is a valid UK location with that name..I've put a filter so that only UK locations are shown hence no results are displayed if only non-UK locations are returned

but on http://maps.google.com the place Launceston returns a valid UK location so it's definitely a valid location.

any ideas what can be done?

Comment: The Geocoding API returns a [location for "Launceston" for me](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Launceston), as does the [Google Maps Javascript API v3 Geocoder](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_example_geo2.asp?addr1=Launceston&geocode=1).  Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: Hi, as previously mentioned, it does return NON-UK addresses, same as your results however I need to return a UK address, this one:https://www.google.co.uk/maps/place/Launceston,+Cornwall/@50.6364207,-4.3839068,14z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m2!3m1!1s0x486b7e30ce76fec1:0xf18aebea9c2fde29 . So, as you can see, google maps has a valid UK location that is not returned here: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Launceston

Comment: You mean like [this one](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Launceston,%20UK)?

Comment: Yes, that's the result I want to display but without the user having to enter UK (in a normal search you only enter your town name, people don't normally enter town, country). Is that possible?

Comment: If you are only looking for UK addresses, you could append the "UK" to the entered query.